# Mongodb for storing correlations

Tags: mongodb

I want my users to be able to store the correlations between objects they have created. For example, there is a "Topics" collection with in it two objects: "earth" and "nature". Afterwards, I want to allow my users to store a correlation/mapping of 0.8 to indicate that those topics are closely related.

If I would store this in a collection called "Correlations" as an object with the two topic IDs and the correlation, this could potentially lead to topics²/2 amount of correlation objects. Is this the only way to store this, or would you solve this differently?

Thanks!

Comment: For schema design in mongoDB (and other no-sql DBs) its very important to first determine the data access patterns (query paths). How are you going to query the data? (e.g. are you using the objects as key to find the correlation? do you need to sort based on correlation?)

Comment: To echo Balafi, there are many ways to store this data, what is best will depend on how you wish to use the data.  What you have proposed, though completely workable and reasonable, seems to be very much in a "relational" style.  As an example, a less relational style might just store the correlation in a single document (depending on how many objects there are).  Hopefully, with better info on your data access patterns we can help you get a better data model.

Comment: I've also run into this problem with how to setup a 'correlation' collection. Generally my queries on it are by the word in question as the _id and that will have all of the words with correlation > 0, but I would like to have it setup so that I can optimize on the correlation itself, e.g. pulling all words correlated with some specified word by more than X.